# Access the sub structure of a shared library in matlab

Tags: c, matlab, shared-libraries

I have a shared library of which the header file contains two stuctures

```
typedef struct
{
int check;
} test_ts;

typedef struct
{
test_ts new_s;
} new_ts;
```

So I load the library in Matlab and try to create a structure pointer to the shared library, like below

```
libMasterStruct = libstruct('test_ts');
```

This works perfectly, where as the below doesn't work.

```
libMasterStruct = libstruct('new_ts');
```

I know this is because of the nested structure within, is there any way i can make this work?